# Why doesn't text-align: center work on ul given it contains text

Tags: css

I read in various places that `text-align: center` only works on text and `inline` elements. It works on my header elements but not my `ul` and blockquote elements. I had to add `display: inline-block` for the `ul` to be centered.

I understand that it works on the headers because, while they the whole element is a block, they contain inline text. But how is that any different from my ul and blockquote elements? Isn't it true that they're also block-level elements that contain text?

For additional reference, see my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/JLwGdY).

Comment: Posting a minimal amount of code would help to weed through all the unnecessary elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`text-align` works when you want to center inline (or inline-block) elements that are contained within a parent block level element. You apply the style to the parent element.

Because `ul` elements are not inline elements, they will not be centered when you apply `text-align: center` to the parent. They are block level elements and block level elements by default take up the remaining space on that line.

To center a block-level element you can give it a specific width then you can apply `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` to the element. So, in your case if you give the `<ul>` element a width and set the margin-left and margin-right to auto it will become centered within its parent div. No need for `text-align: center`.

By default a `<ul>` does not contain text, but an `<li>` does. Therefore you can apply `text-align: center` to an `<li>` element to center the inline text inside of it.

Also, your `<blockquote>` elements only contain block-level elements directly: `<p>` and `<footer>`. They do not contain text as a direct child descendant. And therefore nothing will be centered inside of it. If you only had text inside of it, then the text would be centered.

**Update**

As per your comment on centering and left-aligning, if I am understanding you correctly you can do something like this:

```
<style>
#parent {text-align: center}
#parent ul {display: inline-block; text-align: left}
</style>
<div id="parent">
    <ul>
        <li>....</li>
        <li>....</li>
        <li>....</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The trick here is that you need to override the text-align=center in the ul because otherwise it gets inherited from the parent div.

Comment: Side note: If I were to apply text-align: center to an li element, I don't think there would be a way to keep the text left-aligned while centered.

Comment: @NatalieCardot What do you mean by both left-aligned and centered? Text can only have one alignment?

Comment: @NatalieCardot I have added an addition on to my answer that might help you out. I am not sure if this is what you meant though.

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping the ul in a div, give the div an id, style div using id, with 'text-align: center;'

And get rid of the ul CSS styles that you have.

Comment: sorry only get rid of 'display: inline-block;'